# Lombok annotation Value. Cannot find method 'value'

Tags: spring, lombok

```
@Repository
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DataProvider {


@Value("${db.url}")
private String dbUrl;

}
```

IDE - idea

Plugin installed in IDE,dependecy installed

Comment: You are not using the good import. The value in your code should come from Spring, not Lombok.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

import @ value from import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
it works

Answer (score 3):

1- verifier your import, maybe you imported value from lombok, and it's wrong,so change your import:

```
import lombok.Value;
```

to:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
```